# php url encode issue

Tags: php, urlencode, rawurl

I send out html email on user activation with token that I encode with rawurlencode().

So - link appears in email like this:

```
<a href="http://site.com/auth?action=confirmActivation&amp;user=79&amp;token=zlKoFo%22f%27g%3FtUb%27%29Z~L1%25zKh%5EG%23_Aj%5Ckbbbd4fdb9121b50f643f12c937ab1c03d5f09861" target="_blank">Click here to activate your account</a>
```

When however I click on this link, my page url looks like this:

```
http://site.com/auth?action=confirmActivation&user=79&token=zlKoFo%22f%27g%3FtUb%27%29Z~L1%25zKh^G%23_Aj%5Ckbbbd4fdb9121b50f643f12c937ab1c03d5f09861
```

So - token before (this is how it appear in my email):

```
zlKoFo%22f%27g%3FtUb%27%29Z~L1%25zKh%5EG%23_Aj%5Ckbbbd4fdb9121b50f643f12c937ab1c03d5f09861
```

Token after:

```
zlKoFo%22f%27g%3FtUb%27%29Z~L1%25zKh^G%23_Aj%5Ckbbbd4fdb9121b50f643f12c937ab1c03d5f09861
```

Looks like my browser does some conversion automatically when I click? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because %5E (^) is being urlencoded by PHP (which encodes all non-alphanum chars except -_). This is not RFC-compliant. The browser sees this, and "fixes" the encoding to be RFC-compliant by decoding everything, then encoding only the chars that cause issues in URLs (^ not being one of them). The php [rawurlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) is RFC compliant, but really, the browser may not itself by RFC-compliant, and may only encode things like spaces and ~, etc. I would suggest that you just urldecode whatever token you get and use that result, which will be consistent either way. If you have troublesome chars in the token, [base64 encode it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) to solve that.

Comment: token that I send is RFC 3986 compliant. Browser makes it "uncompliant" when I click on it.

Comment: I think I got it though: My token, while compliant to RFC 3986 (url) standard does contain html special charachters: %22 is ". This way everything will work if I send text emails instead of html ones.

Comment: Browser encounters html special charachters inside of href tag and rightfully converts them into actual charachters.

Comment: I guess if I'd use html emails - I have to use base64(url version) for my tokens. damn